# Dispatch Touch Event Automatically in Android

Tags: touch-event, floating-action-button, dispatch, android-touch-event

Can you give me a code example of how to dispatch a touch event without any user interaction or gesture detection like automatically? The exact dispatch touch code and motion event codes without touching the touchscreen myself.

I want to toggle or hold a simple touch simulation on and off under a floating system action button in Android but I'm having trouble simulating the touch after you press the floating action button. Thanks